# Proxy in package.json not affecting fetch request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, proxy, create-react-app

I am trying to fetch some data from the development server using React.

I am running the client on `localhost:3001` and the backend on `port 3000`.

**The fetch request :**

```
 const users = fetch('/api/users');
    users.then((err,res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

When I run my development server and webpack-dev-server I get the following output:

```
GET http://localhost:3001/api/users 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried specifying the proxy in the *package.json* so it would proxy the request to the API server, however nothing has changed.

Here is my **package.json file**:

[image]

.. and the **webpack.config** :
[image]

Please tell me, if you need to see anything else from my project. I apologies, if I'm missing something and not being thorough, I'm still quite new to using these technologies.

Comment: If your server runs on localhost:3000 then modify your fetchRequest like

`fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users')` also make sure you have cors enabled on your backend

Comment: Does it solve your problem

Comment: Yes, I wanted to proxy the request to the api server, however it's not working, but making a request  directly to `http://localhost:3000/api/users` is working properly.

Comment: I think the problem comes from your naming conventions :)

Comment: These comments don't answer the question of how to effectively use a proxy.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can modify your fetch request API url to give the complete hostname since

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
```

also make sure that you have `CORS` enabled on your backend

In case your want to redirect through webpack, your can try `devServer.proxy` as

```
devServer: { 
    inline: true, 
    contentBase: './dist', 
    port: 3001, 
    proxy: { "/api/**": { target: 'http://localhost:3000', secure: false }  }
 }
```

Comment: You should never enable cors.

Comment: @AakashVerma, I wouldn't agree with your comment completely, you need to enable cors when you need to serve data to a frontend that is on a different domain, however, I would agree that you might want to put a filter on domains that you trust

Comment: Another thing i'd like to add is that make sure `https: false` if your proxy isn't using https otherwise that will cause problems.

Answer (score 18):

I know I'm a little late to the game here, but I'll leave it here for future reference.

To make the devServer proxy work as expected, you need to specify the HTTP Accepts header to be something else than "text/html". Do this with the init-object that fetch accepts as the second argument. A simple example:

```
fetch("/api/profile",{
    headers:{
        "accepts":"application/json"
    }
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();
})
.then(json => console.log(json) )
.catch( a => { console.log(a) });
```

The reason for this is that the WebPack Dev Server normally uses a context/namespace to differentiate between what to serve and what to forward. The create-react-app scripts do not extract a namespace from the proxy path in the `package.json` file. Instead the scripts has the opinionated default behaviour that any request using something else than HTTP GET will get forwarded. Also, anything using HTTP GET, but NOT `text/html` as the `Accepts` header will get forwarded.

The reasoning is because most React Apps are SPA (Single Page Applications) which use AJAX/Fetch to communicate with some API. API's normally use JSON or XML, but not `text/html`.

Comment: Thanks Canis. This was the missing piece for me!

Comment: Thanks. This was the missing link for me. Cheers.

Comment: If you need to accept text/html for a proxied endpoint (e.g. for authentication or other redirect flows) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236347/is-it-possible-to-proxy-the-html-get-request-to-graphql-from-a-create-react-app

Answer (score 9):

In the package.json

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/users": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
},
```

Comment: Got an error: `When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".
Either remove "proxy" from package.json, or make it a string.`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using axios and was only able to get it working by using the complete hostname and enabling Cors.

`const response = await axios.get('http://localhost/users/');`

Install cors

`npm i cors`

Use cors

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  //...
});

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log("CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80");
});
```

[Ref](https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/24/how-to-enable-cors-in-a-react-app-with-node-js-backend/)

Answer (score 2):

The solution by user jellyfish-tom in https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/793#issuecomment-316650146 worked for me.

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "*": "http://[::1]:8081"
    // "secure": false,
    // "changeOrigin": true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack Dev Server uses [`devServer.proxy` config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) in your Webpack config to control proxying requests.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried specifying the proxy in the devServer, however it still doesn't redirect the request to the api server.

`devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist',
        port: 3001,
        proxy: {
          "/api": "http://localhost:3000"
        }
    }`


The general headers in the network tab: 

`Request URL:http://localhost:3001/api/users
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3001`