# Reactjs: post data to localhost always pending

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am working on ReactJs and NodeJS and I am creating a signup page. I post data to server but it is always pending.

Which part did I do wrong? It would be nice if someone can help.

**Front end**:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // prevent page refresh
    event.preventDefault();
    const newUserData = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    axios
      .post("/signup", newUserData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      setEmail("");
      setName("");
      setPassword("")
    console.log("form submitted ✅");
  };
```

**Backend**:

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password || !name) {
    res.status(422).send({ error: "Please add all the fields" });
  }
  console.log(req.body);
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .then((savedUser) => {
      if (savedUser) {
        res.status(422).send({ error: "Email already been used" });
      }
      bcrypt.hash(password, 12).then((hashedpassword) => {
        const user = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password: hashedpassword,
        });
        user
          .save()
          .then((user) => {
            res.json({ message: "Sign Up Successfully" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

in package.json i set proxy as

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Comment: I tested the api through postman and I got the respond instantly. So I think maybe something I did wrong on the front-end part?

Comment: Did you find out why? I'm having the same problem with calls to localhost. If I use any external address it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using MongoDB as well, in that case keep in your mind that the findOne is async, so you need to use `await` before. And for to save data you need to use the `.create()` method from MongoDB, e.g.

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password || !name) {
    res.status(422).send({ error: "Please add all the fields" });
  }
  console.log(req.body);
  await User.findOne({ email: email })
    .then((savedUser) => {
      if (savedUser) {
// you need to add return to stop the code
       return res.status(422).send({ error: "Email already been used" });
      }
// or you can add else because the code keep running
      bcrypt.hash(password, 12).then((hashedpassword) => {
        const user = await User.create({
          name,
          email,
          password: hashedpassword,
        });

        user
          .save()
          .then((user) => {
            res.json({ message: "Sign Up Successfully" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I think it is better to use something like `throw new Error('Email already been used')` instead of return for your `res.status(422).send({ error: "Email already been used" });` because if you have `return` the server doesn't give back an error, but a normal answer, but of course it is ok if you want that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it didn't work. It is just keep pending when I post the data through front-end. 

I tested the api through postman and I got the respond instantly. So maybe something I did wrong on the front-end part?

Comment: In this case, try to add `async` and `await` before axios call, for the same reason as before. Because, what I think may happen is, the `setEmail(""); setName(""); setPassword("")` are being called before axios.

Comment: And just in case if is any error with the proxy set-up, test it like this : `await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/signup", newUserData).then((res) => console.log(res.data)).catch((error)=>console.log(error));`

Comment: It didn't help after I added `async` and `await`. I even removed `setEmail(""); setName(""); setPassword("")` and it still remain the same pending status.

I took your suggestion on proxy set-up texting, and it showed an error `POST http://localhost:5000/signup 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`. What should I do to fix it.

Comment: I haven't seen `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` again... So, I posted a new answer, please if you can, try it and tell me the results.

Answer (score 0):

I want you to be sure that before you submit, the values `name, email, password,` are updated. Please try:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // prevent page refresh
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`The value for the name: ${name}`);
    console.log(`The value for the email: ${email}`);
    console.log(`The value for the password: ${password}`);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/signup", {
        name,
        email,
        password,
      });
      console.log(response.data);
      setEmail("");
      setName("");
      setPassword("");
      console.log("form submitted ✅");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Case 1: I didn't input any name, email or password
Case 2: I input all the field but the email is already been used
Case 3: I input all the field and the email has not been used

In the console, `name, email, password` are all updated in all 3 cases. I got `POST http://localhost:5000/signup 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` in case 1 and 2, which is the expected result based on my backend. For case 3 I successfully registered, which is also the expected result.

Comment: However I got 2 respond in all 3 cases. Besides the expected responds (status 422 for case 1 and 2, status 200 for case 3), I got an extra respond status 204 no content for all 3 cases. Is it normal to have this status 204 respond?

Comment: Besides the extra respond, it seems that it is working if I post data using the link `http://localhost:5000/signup` directly and without setting the proxy. If I post data using `/signup` and I set `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` in `package.json`, the result is always pending. Is there any way that I can set up the proxy correctly so I can use `/signup` to post data.

Comment: About the 2 responses, as I told you in my first comment, you need to add `return` in your back end code, because the code keeps running. My opinion is instead of `return` add `throw` in your back end. Now, I'm not sure what's going wrong in your proxy's setup, you can have a look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291950/proxy-not-working-for-react-and-node)

Comment: The response 204 means that _the request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to navigate away from its current page_, and you shouldn't have it, so check in your back end all cases you send a response.

Answer (score 0):

### Change localhost to 127.0.0. for node 17 or higher

I hade the same problem working with Node>=17. It had worked with 16.

For me changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 worked.