# React/Express app not using proxy in package.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Creating my first React (frontend)/Express (backend) app (3000:5000 respectively). Both are running but when I setup a proxy in my frontend package.js, the frontend is still trying to grab localhost:3000 and is not using the proxy to request data from the backend. I noticed that my package-lock.js doesn't the proxy reference like my package.js does. Is package-lock.js not updating? Or is this another issue?

```
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {..
```

I deleted the package-lock.json and regenerated it but no proxy mentioned in it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxy in package.json not affecting fetch request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365577/proxy-in-package-json-not-affecting-fetch-request)

Comment: It was asked already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365577/proxy-in-package-json-not-affecting-fetch-request/50118381