# proxy in package.json not working in frontend folder while its working in admin folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

1. this is my package.json with the proxy that i'm using,
   I've tried to use cors inside index.js in backend but it didn't work, I've also tried to to make .env file and write my proxy inside it, but it didn't work.
   this process it working on my admin folder

```
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.49.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365577/proxy-in-package-json-not-affecting-fetch-request Did you check this? Looks very close to what you are trying, check 3rd answer that suggests fetch to be used with header as well!