# POST http://localhost:3000/users/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

my react app running on localhost 3000 and server on localhost 8000
i tried to fill login form connected to mongodb but i am getting this error  POST http://localhost:3000/users/login 404 (Not Found)
nextlines it displyats axious error

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';
const Login = () => {
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const submitHandler=async(values) =>{
        try{  setLoading(true)
              const{data} = await axios.post('/users/login',values) 
              setLoading(false) 
              message.success('login sucess')
              localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify({...data,password:''}))
              navigate('/')
        }catch(error){
            setLoading(false)
            message.error('Some Thing went Wrong')
            console.log(error);
        }
      };


export default Login
```

i am using proxy in react app package.json

```
"proxy":"http://localhost::8000/api/v1",
```

server code

```
const router = require('./router/router');
Routes
app.use('/api/v1/users', require('./router/router'));
//Port
const PORT = 8000 ||process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`The server is listing at ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: Refer to this link below https://stackoverflow.com/a/44366795/6080567