# Why Unexpected token error come and not show any data?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch, mern

I'm following a youtube tutorial about mern stack and not i have this issue..I tried so many tricks and solution in chatgpt / documentations.still can't figure out what happen in here.. backend was work fine when i run it using postmon

this is the error

```
Home.jsx:33 Network error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
```

**I added both backend and frontend file with this question. I really need help from you to find this issue**

//home.jsx

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Home() {
    const [workouts,setWorkouts]=useState(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchWorkout=async()=>{

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/workouts');
                const json = await response.json();
    
                if (response.ok) {
                    setWorkouts(json);
                } else {
                    console.error('Error fetching workouts:', json);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Network error:', error);
            }}

            fetchWorkout()

    },[])

  return (
    <div className='home'>
        <div className="workouts">

            {/* if workout exist and this map method run..but its null this code not work */}
            {workouts && workouts.map((workout)=>(
                <p key={workout._id}>{workout.title}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

package.json

```
{
    "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
    "name": "frontend",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    ..........
```

//this is server.js in backend

```
//attached environment veriables to the process
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const workoutRoutes = require('./routes/workouts.js')
const cors = require('cors')

//creatd express app
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: "input the localhost in your frontend" }))

//register the midleware()
//any code that execute between getting request on the server and sending the response
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path, req.method);
    next();
})

app.use(express.json())


//routing
/* app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: "welcome to the application" })
})
 */

app.use('/api/workouts', workoutRoutes);

//connect to db
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        //port listing
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log("Connect to the DB & cd backendApp Listen on port ", process.env.PORT)
        })
    })
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

//this is workout.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { createWorkout, deleteWorkout, updateWorkout, getWorkOuts, getWorkout } = require('../controller/workoutController')
const router = express.Router();

const Workout = require('../models/Workout')

//GET all workout
/* router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        msg: "GET all workouts",
    })
})
 */
router.get('/', getWorkOuts)


//GET a single Workout
/* router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        id: 2,
        name: "customized workout"
    })
}) */
router.get('/:id', getWorkout)


//POST a new workout
/* router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const { title, load, reps } = req.body

    try {
        const workout = await Workout.create({ title, load, reps })
        res.status(200).json(workout)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    }
    res.json({ msg: "post a new workout" }) 

}) */

router.post('/', createWorkout)

//POST a new workout(self practice)
router.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const student = ["kamal", "nimal", "sunil", "supun"]
    res.json({
        msg: "post a new students",
        st: student[req.params.id]
    })
})

//DELETE a new workout
/* router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        msg: "Delete a new workout"
    })
})
 */
router.delete('/:id', deleteWorkout)




//UPDTAE a new workout
/* router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: "Update a new workout" })
}) */

router.patch('/:id', updateWorkout)



//export rounter
module.exports = router;
```

//this is workoutcontroller.jsx

```
const Workout = require('../models/Workout')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//get all workout
const getWorkOuts = async(req, res) => {
    const workouts = await Workout.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 })

    res.status(200).json(workouts)
}

//get single workout
const getWorkout = async(req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params

    //if id not valid
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(404).send("No workout with this ID")
    }

    const workout = await Workout.findById(id)

    if (!workout) {
        return res.status(400).json("No workout with this id")
    }

    res.status(200).json(workout)
}

//create new workout
const createWorkout = async(req, res) => {
    const { title, load, reps } = req.body

    //add doc to odb
    try {
        const workout = await Workout.create({ title, load, reps })
        res.status(200).json(workout)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    }
}

//delete workout
const deleteWorkout = async(req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(404).send("No workout with this ID")
    }

    const workout = await Workout.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: id })

    if (!workout) {
        return res.status(400).json("No workout with this id")
    }

    res.status(200).json(workout)


}

//update workout

    const updateWorkout = async(req, res) => {
        const { id } = req.params
    
        if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
            return res.status(404).send("No workout with this ID")
        }
    
        const workout = await Workout.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {
            ...req.body
        });
    
        if (!workout) {
            return res.status(400).json("No workout with this id")
        }
    
        res.status(200).json(workout)
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    module.exports = {
        createWorkout,
        deleteWorkout,
        getWorkOuts,
        getWorkout,
        updateWorkout
    }
```

Comment: As the error says its a Network error, check Chrome console. Do you see any CORS or 404 errors? The fetch function expects a JSON but if an error like 404 encounter you will get an html page as response. The error is due to this.

Comment: See this post also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365577/proxy-in-package-json-not-affecting-fetch-request

Comment: I guess the response is not JSON and also maybe the above points as well ...

Comment: @kiranvj there is no error in chrome console.only show this error. i try to commenting `const response = await fetch('/api/workouts');` `//const json = await response.json();` and console.log response.. it show   `Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:5173/api/workouts', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue. Your backend is running on port `5173` . Is your ReactJS app also running on the same port `5173` ?

Comment: yes.. I thought that url connected to frontend....yes it is the port that react app running